# Did most colleges in the United States have semesters that began in September and ended in January during the 1890s?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, education

I have been researching college calendars from the 1890s and have found that their semesters are very different from most "modern" semesters in the United States. Here are two examples: [Texas](http://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth41702/m1/25/), [Bryn Mawr](http://archive.org/stream/brynmawrcolleg9596bryn#page/4/mode/2up)

My question is this: did all colleges operate under this system, or did some begin their semesters in August and end them in December, as many do now? I'd like to know the history of the college semester system in the United States.

Comment: Every school sets up its own calendar, but for what it's worth, Cornell's fall semester ran September to January until 1965. I'm sure they weren't the only one.

Comment: Princeton still has (barring COVID) a reading period and finals in January as part of the fall semester.